# In Go, is there any aji left in this corner enclosure (3-5, 4-4, 6-3), and if so, how can it be invaded?

Tags: go

I often see the following three stone corner enclosure made in high level games, when the player wants to further secure his corner.

[image]

This enclosure does not appear on the sensei's library page for 3-3 invasions:
http://senseis.xmp.net/?AllAbout33PointInvasion%2FDiagrams

Does any aji remain for white to invade this position in some way?  If so, what is the best way to invade it, and what is the expected result?

Comment: That pattern just showed up in a game between pros https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jsyULqx-S20

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the addition of the P17 stone, the enclosure is considered safe. The standard response to white R17 is black R16. R17 is a probe rather than an attempt to live, and in practice black's best answer will depend on the surrounding stones.

See these two links for more information:

http://senseis.xmp.net/?443563Enclosure

http://senseis.xmp.net/?4435Enclosure

Even without the presence of the P17 stone, [the best white can get locally is a ko](http://senseis.xmp.net/?4463Enclosure33Invasion).

If you [search this pattern on eidogo.com](http://eidogo.com/#search:ne:7x6:.15x.8x.7x.9), you'll see that this enclosure usually ends up as black territory.

Comment: Thanks, so if white invaded, say at the 3-3 point, would black play S15 in the diagram and attempt to kill it outright?

Comment: @Hal answer edited with two more links

Comment: Thank you, I tried to find it on sensei's library but couldnt, because I kept looking for '354463' enclosure instead.